# Displaying Large CLOBS in Oracle APEX 5.1.4

Tags: oracle-apex

**Dear All,**

I had a problem retrieving a clob from the database and displaying it in an apex Check box.  The reason for this is it is a very large clob and Apex item have a 32k character (byte) limit. This is because PL/SQL treats oracle apex page items as varchars not clobs and varchars have a maximum size. Anything over that size will not be displayed.

I checked one blog about these problem and also applied but problem is not solved.

[http://mayo-tech-ans.blogspot.com/2013/06/displaying-large-clobs-in-oracle-apex.html][1]

Database Version     ::: 12.1.0.2.0

Apex Version         :::  5.1.4

Thanks in advance

**Regards,**

**Sultan**

Answer (score 3):

Apex items can never be over 32 KB, that's the PL/SQL limit and there's not much you can do about that.

I question whether you really need a checkbox that has a value of > 32 KB. Could you use some other value like the primary key of the row for the CLOB, or an MD5 hash of it?

If you need to display some large content, like some large amount of text in a region, there is the OraOpenSource [clob-load](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-plugin-clob-load) plugin.

You can also take a CLOB and chunk it up and write it out as HTML using the `htp` package. I gave an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904376/how-to-insert-base64-encoded-img-src-attribute-into-table-in-oracle-and-then-dis).

Comment: a new version of such plugin was released:
https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:1595107295329::::P710_PLG_ID:APEX.CLOB.LOAD.2