# How to insert base64 encoded img src attribute into table in Oracle and then display it on the page in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

My requirement is to insert img src values into table and then display in on the apex page.
How can I do that?

I have created a function which inserts the img src into CLOB column
But incase the length exceeds 32000 it doesnt insert it to the CLOB column

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085147/can-i-store-binary-string-in-clob-column/42086105#42086105

Comment: Thanks for the link - but I'm a bit cofused here.I should be converting my base64 encoded to blob, store it to the table and to display it - I need it to convert it back to clob.Is it?

Comment: In my link I provided two functions for conversion in both ways, what do you need?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What do u suggest I do here - I have a base64 encoded string - which is a data URI , should I convert it to BLOB, insert it to table and then for display - convert it back to CLOB?

Comment: Also, the base encoded string has the character limit for CLOB and BLOB.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your data is getting truncated at 32000 characters (probably actually 32767) means you have some intermediate `VARCHAR2`. Other than that, there's not enough information here.

Once you get your base64 encoded data, to display it on an Apex page, the easiest way to do that is with a PL/SQL region and the `htp` package. None of the native `htp` functions support CLOBs, so you will have to output it in chunks. Something like this:

```
i:= 1;
loop
    l_chunk := dbms_lob.substr( l_b64_clob, l_chunk_size, i );
    exit when l_chunk is null;
    htp.prn( l_chunk );
    i := i + l_chunk_size;
end loop;
```

I suggest you write a reusable procedure to do this.

Comment: The chunk size could be defined as you want.